# pre select option using ng-model-options

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

This is my `scope.projectArr` array

```
scope.projectArr = [  
   {  
      "proName":"fffff",
      "proId":"12"
   },
   {  
      "proName":"project 0001",
      "proId":"13"
   },
   {  
      "proName":"ABC website",
      "proId":"7"
   }
];
```

Again i have a another object that has a property called `project` and contain a string value

```
$scope.timesheet = {};
$scope.timesheet.project = "ABC website";
```

my question is i want all the array element as options and pre select an option based on `$scope.timesheet.project` value. I tried this using `ng-model-options="{trackBy: $value.proName}"` But unable to do so

here is the html

```
<md-select placeholder="Project" ng-model="timesheet.project" 
   flex  ng-model-options="{trackBy: $value.proName}">
   <md-optgroup label="Project">
   <md-option  ng-repeat="item in projectArr"  ng-value="item">{{item.proName}}    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

i tried using curly brackets inside `ng-value` but the same result.

i look up the inspect element to check whether values assign to options but it show as `[object object]`

[image]`

Please note that i'm using angular material and as far for my knowledge `ng-option` is not available in the material.

don't get confuse by the `vm.projectArr` in the image. i'm using controllerAs in my app but for simplicity sake i post this question as scope variables.

Comment: Did you try setting `$scope.timesheet.project = "ABC website";` in the same controller where your template resides?

Comment: yep its same one

Answer (score 1):

## Update

You can make use of ng-model-options like below:
You missed quotes around trackBy expression

```
<md-select placeholder="Project" ng-model="timesheet.project" flex ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.proName'}">
  <md-optgroup label="Project">
    <md-option ng-repeat="item in projectArr" ng-value="item">{{item.proName}} </md-option>
</md-select>
```

In your controller use below:

```
$scope.timesheet = {
    'project': {
        'proName': "ABC website"
    }
};
```

[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qG5us6?p=preview)

---

I was able to get it working by using

```
$scope.timesheet = {
    'project': arrFilter($scope.projectArr, 'proName', 'ABC website')[0]
};
```

arrFilter method: this method takes an `array`,  `property name`, `property value` and returns the array from array of objects.

```
function arrFilter(arr, prop, val) {
    return arr.filter(function(v) {
        debugger;
        return v[prop].indexOf(val) > -1
    }) || [];
}
```

### Working demo

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0BdL0Y?p=preview)

### Explanation:

Since your options getting objects, you should provide the `same object reference` which arrFilter is doing.
The reason for doing so is, in javascript object comparison is done by reference not value.
Example:

```
{} never equals to {}
```

but a={}, b=a and `a equals b`

Comment: is there any way i can do this with out getting the reference from the array

Comment: I guess you could make use of track by in ng-repeat!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
ng-value ="item.proId"

```
<md-select placeholder="Project" ng-model="timesheet.project" 
   flex  ng-model-options="{trackBy: $value.proName}">
   <md-optgroup label="Project">
   <md-option  ng-repeat="item in projectArr"  ng-value="item.proId">{{item.proName}}    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: i need the whole `item` object as  ng-model value, This way ng-model value gonna be  `proId` value only

Comment: Change ng-model-option

<md-select placeholder="Project" ng-model="timesheet.project"
                               flex  ng-model-options="{trackBy: $value}">
                        <md-optgroup label="Project">
                            <md-option  ng-repeat="item in projectArr"  ng-value="{{item}}">{{item.proName}}    </md-option>
                        </md-optgroup>
                    </md-select>

Answer (score 0):

It should be like to this

```
$scope.timesheet = {};
$scope.timesheet.project = $scope.projectArr[0];
```

***Edit:***

```
 <md-select placeholder="Project" ng-model="timesheet.project" >
   <md-option  ng-repeat="item in projectArr"  
    ng-value="item.proName">     {{item.proName}} </md-option>
 </md-select>
```

and init like this

```
 $scope.timesheet.project = $scope.theStringValue; //ABC website
```

or similar to this

```
  <md-select placeholder="Project" ng-model="timesheet.project" >
   <md-option  ng-repeat="item in projectArr"  
    ng-value="item.proId">     {{item.proName}} </md-option>
 </md-select>
```

and for default selected value

```
   angular.forEach($scope.projectArr,function(proj){
      if(proj.proName == $scope.theStringValue)
        $scope.timesheet.project = proj.proId;
   })
```

Comment: i'm getting the string value and projectArr values from two separate http call.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your model in the controller as

```
$scope.timesheet.project = $scope.projectArr[2]
```

Or in your view as

```
<div ng-init="timesheet.project = projectArr[2]">
    <md-select placeholder="Project" ng-model="timesheet.project" flex>
       <md-optgroup label="Project">
       <md-option  ng-repeat="item in projectArr">{{item.proName}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</div>
```

This will initialize it to 3rd object and show 'ABC website'